# Is this is a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?

Tags: java

Is this is a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 2621440 bytes for GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_23/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=31746, tid=1527241616
#  Error: GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_23/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b01
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (19.0-b06 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Additional info:

```
vm_info: OpenJDK Server VM (19.0-b06) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_23-ea-b01), built on Aug 30 2010 01:02:45 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"linux-x86" implies it is 32-bit.

Comment: @StephenC Or possibly "linux-amd64".

Comment: Is there an AMD specific spin of OpenJDK?

Comment: @StephenC No, but x86-64 is sometimes referred to as [amd64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). They are one in the same.